# Failed integration between C# and Python using same schema on schema registry

Tags: python, c#, .net, schema, avro

**Problem Description**

We have C# code which is producing records on Kafka and use an Avro schema, we can consume the same topic by C# as well, but when we want to consume it in Python, we get the following error:

> Message deserialization failed: Message deserialization failed for message at [topic name] [4] offset 17: message does not start with magic byte`

and also this procedure is fine when we produce by Python and consume by Python as well.

**P.S.** `IAsyncSerializer` is used in C# and `AvroConsumer` in Python code.

We have tried to serialize records in C# and deserialize the in Python based on the same Avro schema on schema registry.

**Question:**

Could you please help me if you had such experience before?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you are using a confluent avro serializer on the C# side. For example, if you look at something like this https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.SchemaRegistry.Serdes.AvroSerializer-1.html you'll see it mentions how the first 5 bytes are magic bytes. Those are the same ones the python code is complaining about not existing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is better to put the code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

This is the C# code which was questioned in this topic.
The schema can be retrieved by this line of code and it can be convertet to Avro schema.

GetSchemaRegistry().GetLatestSchemaAsync("SchemaRegistrySubject").Result.Schema

---

```
using Avro.IO;
using Avro.Specific;
using Confluent.Kafka;

public class KafkaAvroSerializer<T> : IAsyncSerializer<T>
where T : class, ISpecificRecord
{
    public Task<byte[]> SerializeAsync(T data, SerializationContext context)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
       {
           using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
           {
               var enc = new BinaryEncoder(ms);
               var writer = new SpecificDefaultWriter(data.Schema);
               writer.Write(data, enc);
               return ms.ToArray();
           }
      });
   }
}
```

---

```
using Avro;
using Avro.Specific;

public class MyRecord : ISpecificRecord
{
   public Schema Schema =>
    Schema.Parse(@”Schema.Parse @"{
      ""name"": ""name "",
      ""namespace"": ""namespace"",
      ""type"": ""record"",
      ""fields"": [
        {
          ""name"": ""field1"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""int""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        },
        {
          ""name"": ""field2"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""string""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        },
        {
          ""name"": ""field3"",
          ""type"": [
            ""null"",
            ""string""
          ],
          ""default"": null
        }
      ]
    }");

public int field1 { get; set; }
public string field2 { get; set; }
public string field3 { get; set; }

public object Get(int fieldPos)
{
    switch (fieldPos)
    {
        case 0: return field1;
        case 1: return field2;
        case 2: return field3;
        default: throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in 
 Get()");
    };
}

public void Put(int fieldPos, object fieldValue)
{
    switch (fieldPos)
    {
        case 0: field1= (int)fieldValue; break;
        case 1: field2= (string)fieldValue; break;
        case 2: field3= (string)fieldValue; break;
        default: throw new AvroRuntimeException("Bad index " + fieldPos + " in 
        Put()");
    };
  }
}
```

---

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.SchemaRegistry;
public async Task Publish<T>(T @event) where T 
{
    using (var producer = GetProducer())
    {
        try
        {
            if (@event == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var kafkaEvent = KafkaEventFactory.Create(@event);
            
            var avroModel = AvroModelFactory.Create(kafkaEvent);
            var message = new Message<string, MyRecord>() { Value = avroModel, Key = kafkaEvent.Key };

            var deliveryResult = await producer.ProduceAsync(_kafkaOption.Topic, message);
            _logger.LogInformation($"Delivered '{deliveryResult.Value}' to '{deliveryResult.TopicPartitionOffset}'");
        }
        catch (ProduceException<string, MyRecord> e)
        {
            _logger.LogError($"Delivery failed: {e.Error.Reason}");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
private IProducer<string, MyRecord> GetProducer()
{
    var config = GetProducerConfig();
    var schemaRegistry = GetSchemaRegistry();

    var producer = new ProducerBuilder<string, MyRecord >(config)
        .SetErrorHandler((_, error) =>
        {
            _logger.LogError(error.ToString());
        })
        .SetValueSerializer(new KafkaAvroSerializer< MyRecord >())
        .Build();

    return producer;
}

private ProducerConfig GetProducerConfig()
{
    return new ProducerConfig
    {
        BootstrapServers = “BootstrapServers”
    };
}

private CachedSchemaRegistryClient GetSchemaRegistry()
{
    return new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(new SchemaRegistryConfig { Url = 
 “SchemaRegistryUrl” });
 }
```